# Icon won't center align in button

Tags: html, css

I have a button set up like this:

I cannot for the life of me get the icon to sit in the middle of the button.

This is my CSS:

```
.buttonclass {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #1DBE60
}


.iconclass {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 7.5px;
}
```

The only caveat is that I need the margin on the iconclass.

Here's a plunk...

http://plnkr.co/edit/6fLYQlpFmDdf7aWenBtp?p=preview

Comment: Have you tried using: `<input type="image">` for button images?

Comment: I'd suggest using image via the css background-image rule.

Comment: Why do you need the margin on the `.iconclass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the image as a background-image is probably your best bet.

If you can't do that then I would probably create a css rule for that `.iconclass` nested in that `.buttonclass` since you said you cannot remove the margin from the `.iconclass` directly.

Something like this:

```
.buttonclass .iconclass{
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4BNXlwD4LW8lFG8d1hpE?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Look into box-sizing, this will help it contain it's content and you can adjust the width/height from there. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Works well like this:

```
.buttonclass {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #1DBE60;
  box-sizing:content-box;
  padding:0px;
}    

.iconclass {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was toggling your CSS file, and I believe this simple solution works...

you could also resize the ewisth of the icon class, but this seems to be what you're looking for if I'm correct

**CSS**

```
.buttonclass {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #1DBE60
}

.iconclass {
width:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution (alter only image class)

```
.iconclass {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 3.4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `margin: 0px -2px -2px -2px;` to the `.iconclass`.